# Embed all projects into a unique executable

Tags: c#, dll, build, embed

I've got a solution with two projects. 
A first "master" project which is a winform project, a second library project.
The first project has a reference on the second one (References->Add Reference->Projects...) and the second project has a reference to an existing dll. 
When I build the solution, I have three files into the bin folder, namely :
Application.exe / library1.dll / library2.dll

How do I embed the two dll into the executable file ??

Comment: It is a request from users of my application. Easier to deploy... even if I disagree

Comment: I saw these questions too, but in my case, the dll are not pre-existing ones, they are part of my solution. They are references, not ressources.